# You must complete the advertising ID declaration before releasing an app that targets Android 13

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, declaration, google-advertising-id

It's about several days I'm fighting with Google declaration. I tried "No", I tried "Yes" with almost all option selected but still, once I submit declaration, it is gone but after some time it appears again.

What can be the issue? My app is built with Unity. Should I add/change something on App side? Why I still get message from Google that I need to fill declaration form despite how I fill?

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you opening it from the "top message" which appears in Google Console? If you choose your app -> scroll to the very bottom -> policy -> app content -> do you still have your declaration under the "todo" list instead of "completed"?

Comment: Yes, I'm opening from "Top message" and it's quite annoying since the message is still there. 

But if I go App->AppContent then it says that "Advertising ID" is submitted and marked with green tickle.

Comment: Then I would say that it's another annoying bug related to the advertisement ID and you should forget about it - it will disappear eventually. We already discussed here with some other folks that this advertisement ID stuff has some not so funny bugs like ignoring the included permission in the manifest file while submitting a new build and it throws you a warning and so on. I'm assuming and hoping that it will be fixed from the Google side in the near future.